# Not able to Install Gmplot in python Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I want to install  gmplot on Anaconda ( I am user 64 bit Windows 10)

https://anaconda.org/mlgill/gmplot

---

run below command:

conda install -c mlgill gmplot=1.1.1

But I get this error message:

> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current
>   win-64 channels:
>     - gmplot 1.1.1*

Answer (score 2):

Go to Python console in Anaconda .
Use

> pip install gmplot

Comment: After installing it through pip, how do you call it to be executed? I tried `gmplot -V` to see which version I'm using but it's not working.

Comment: This may be already answered elsewhere. @Zap you can, open command prompt from anaconda and do "pip search module_name "

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mayank Khandelwal,

As you send the link is of OSX, for windows you can use below github link.

https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot

Use setup.py to install.

Comment: But I need install in Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

@Zap, after installation, you need to import the library before you can use it. Here is a simple flow. Open an Anaconda Prompt then type following commands

```
pip install gmplot
```

once installation is finished. Then launch a python console and import the library,

```
import gmplot
```

now you can use it directly as you want. For example,

```
import gmplot

# Create the map plotter:
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(37.766956, -122.448481, 14, apikey=apikey)
```